# Apply same style to multyple objects that match specific criteria wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, resources

In my application I have several menus with the same background color, corner radius,border color and border thickness. I save those properties as resources in my application resources so that if I change the background color for example it will change the color of all my menus. I was wondering if it is possible to create a style so that I can just bind that style to the menus instead of binding so many properties. Moreover I just want to apply that style to some borders because not all borders in my application are menus. How could I do that?

for example I am hoping to do something like:

here is my style in my application resources:

```
     <Style x:Key="someStyle">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Color x:Key="MenuBackground2">#BB252525</Color>
            <CornerRadius x:Key="CornerRadiusMenu2">7</CornerRadius>
            <Border x:Key="MainBorder2" >
                <Border.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource MenuBackground}"/>
                </Border.Background>
            </Border>
        </Style.Resources>                       
    </Style>
```

and then on MainWindow.xaml place:

```
<Border Margin="498,90,25,0" Name="brdMain" Style="{DynamicResource someStyle}"></Border>
```

but when I do that, brdMain does not seem to bind to that style...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Style` is not correctly defined. It should be a collection of `Setters`. For example, your given style should be:

```
 <Style x:Key="someStyle">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#BB252525"/>
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="7"/>
    etc ...                      
</Style>
```

A `Style` is little more than a bunch of property setters. You can only set properties of the object to which the `Style` has been applied.

Comment: CornerRadius does not work. also I need to specify border thickness. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <Style x:Key="someStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
        <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="#BB252525"/>
        <Setter Property="Control.BorderThickness" Value=".5"/>
        <Setter Property="Control.BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="7"/>                                     
    </Style>
```